# GregorianCalendar can't add 97 days?

Tags: java, scala, date, gregorian-calendar

I'm creating 3 GregorianCalendar objects:

1. December 4, 2018
2. December 4, 2018 + 96 days
3. December 4, 2018 + 97 days

The day difference between the first and the second is 96 days.  The day difference between the first and the third is... *96 days*. Say hunh?

Apologies for the Scala code, but you Java-heads should be able to get what's going on:

```
def test(): Unit = {
    val start = new GregorianCalendar(2018, 11, 4)
    val laterA = new GregorianCalendar(2018, 11, 4)
    laterA.add(Calendar.DATE, 96)
    val laterB = new GregorianCalendar(2018, 11, 4)
    laterB.add(Calendar.DATE, 97)
    println(ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(start.toInstant, laterA.toInstant))
    println(ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(start.toInstant, laterB.toInstant))
  }
```

The above prints the following:

```
96
96
```

What's the deal?

Comment: Prints `96, 97` on my laptop. What time zone are you in?

Comment: Don't use the old Date API. It is flawed. Use the new Java Time API. But, if you want to learn what is really happening, and why it is failing, **print the values** of the 3 `toInstant` calls. This is called **debugging**, and will help you figure it out. Example: Since I'm in US Eastern time zone, `start.toInstant()` prints `2018-12-04T05:00:00Z`. As you can see, the `GregorianCalendar` constructor has applied the time zone, exactly as **documented** in the javadoc: *Constructs a GregorianCalendar with the given date set in the **default time zone** with the default locale.*

Comment: @OleV.V. -- Thanks for the toZonedDateTime tip!  I wish you had submitted your comment as an answer as your suggestion allowed me to fix my code.  Gracias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have said already, avoid the `GregorianCalendar` class if you can. It’s got some design problems and is now long outdated.

However, your particular problem was not with the `GregorianCalendar` class. It adds 97 days nicely in your code, taking summer time (DST) into account and everything. As others have correctly pointed out, adding 97 days to December 4 this year gives you March 11, the day when summer time has just begun in those North American time zones that use summer time (month 11 as constructor argument meaning December, another confusing thing about `GregorianCalendar`). Therefore the last day added was only 23 hours long.

Your real issue is with the combination of `ChronoUnit.DAYS` and `Instant`. An `Instant` is a point in time with no time zone and doesn’t have a concept of days. Instead the result you get is the same as you would get from counting hours, dividing by 24 and throwing away the remainder. That’s seldom useful. And since the last day added was only 23 hours, it is not being counted. Instead count days between `ZonedDateTime` or `LocalDate` instances, or some other java.time class that has “date” in its name. Example 1 (Java code, can you translate yourself?):

```
    LocalDate start = LocalDate.of(2018, Month.DECEMBER, 4);
    LocalDate laterB = start.plusDays(97);
    System.out.println(ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(start, laterB));
```

Output:

> 97

If you cannot avoid getting a `GregorianCalendar` from a legacy API that you cannot afford to upgrade just now, the first thing you should do is to convert it using `toZonedDateTime` to get a `ZonedDateTime`. This will give you all the relevant information from the `GregorianCalendar`, including its time zone and its calendar date. In other words, you should not use its `toInstant` method as you did in the code in the question. Example 2:

```
    GregorianCalendar start = new GregorianCalendar(2018, Calendar.DECEMBER, 4);
    GregorianCalendar laterB = new GregorianCalendar(2018, Calendar.DECEMBER, 4);
    laterB.add(Calendar.DATE, 97);
    System.out.println(ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(start.toZonedDateTime(),
                                               laterB.toZonedDateTime()));
```

The output is now the one you had expected:

> 97

I have run both snippets with America/New_York as my default time zone.

Answer (score 7):

You must be in a locale in the USA (or a locale that starts Daylight Saving Time at the same time as the USA does).  In 2019, [DST starts at 2:00 am Sunday, March 10, 2019](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/usa?year=2019).

Adding 96 days from December 4, 2018 yields March 10, 2019.  Adding 97 days from December 4, 2018 yields March 11, 2019.

Formatting and outputting `laterA` and `laterB` yields:

```
2019-03-10 00:00:00
2019-03-11 00:00:00
```

Note that there are 23 hours between those 2 dates because of DST (in the USA).

But the [`between` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalUnit.html#between(java.time.temporal.Temporal,java.time.temporal.Temporal)) truncates fractional units.

> The calculation returns a whole number, representing the number of complete units between the two temporals. For example, the amount in hours between the times 11:30 and 13:29 will only be one hour as it is one minute short of two hours.

So a difference of 96 days, 23 hours (not 97 days because of DST) is returned as `96`.

Answer (score 2):

That's because of your time zone. If you compare the second value by doing

```
System.out.println(ChronoUnit.SECONDS.between(start.toInstant(), laterA.toInstant()));
System.out.println(ChronoUnit.SECONDS.between(start.toInstant(), laterB.toInstant()));
```

you will see that for `Europe/London` you will get

```
8294400
8380800
```

but for `America/New_York` it will be

```
8294400
8377200
```

the difference in second is exactly `3600` second which implies daylight saving time change.

Answer (score 1):

jshell> System.out.println(laterB.toInstant());
2019-03-11T04:00:00Z

jshell> System.out.println(laterA.toInstant());
2019-03-10T05:00:00Z

Notice that the difference is less than 24 hours.  Why?  You crossed a daylight-savings-time boundary on March 10th.